# retrieve variable value from nsh file nsis

Tags: windows, installation, service, macros, nsis

I am creating installer using nsis. I have created .nsh file using SIMPLE SC to start, stop and remove services. I have used macros for this.

When I call this in nsi file it works. But I would like to know the return value for start service (SimpleSC::StartService "${SVC}" "${Args}" "${Timeout}", Pop $0). how do I retrieve the $0 value of nsh file in my nsis file

Comment: We need more information. Does your nsh have macros you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have some helper macros that return a result, you can leave the result on the stack:

```
!macro DoSomething
Push $0
Push $1

Push "Pretend that this is a function that does something and puts the result on the stack"
Pop $0 ; Result we want to return

Pop $1
Exch $0
!macroend

!insertmacro DoSomething
Pop $0
MessageBox MB_OK $0
```

or store it in a register as part of the macro:

```
!macro DoSomething outvar
Push $0
Push $1

Push "Pretend that this is a function that does something and puts the result on the stack"
Pop $0 ; Result we want to return

Pop $1
Exch $0
Pop ${outvar}
!macroend

!insertmacro DoSomething $0
MessageBox MB_OK $0
```

Comment: !define ServiceStartType `!insertmacro ServiceServiceStartType`
!macro ServiceStartType ServiceName Type StartType
Push $0
Push $1
Push ${StartType}
    SimpleSC::ExistsService "${ServiceName}"
    Pop $0 ; returns an errorcode if the service doesn´t exists (<>0)/service exists (0)
    ${If} $0 == 0
        SimpleSC::SetServiceStartType "${ServiceName}" "${Type}"
        Pop $0 ; returns an errorcode (<>0) otherwise success (0)
        Pop $1
        Exch $0
        Pop ${StartType}$StartType ${StartType}"    ${Else}
        Return
    ${Endif}
    Pop $1
    Exch $0
!macroend

Comment: !insertmacro ServiceStartType "FDResPub" 2 $0
    Pop $0
    MessageBox MB_OK "$0"
    ${If} $0 != 0
        MessageBox MB_OK "ERROR = Unable to stop fdPHost Service"
        Abort
    ${Else}
        MessageBox MB_OK "fdPHost service stop successfully"
    ${EndIf}

Comment: above is my code... it always invalid opt code..cant make out what is wrong